# Hiding navbar function not working useLocation

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Can anyone tell me why this function is not giving me the desired results. Have I missed something obvious? When I console log

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Components/Home'
import Welcome from './Components/Welcome'
import About from './Components/About'
import Contact from './Components/Contact'


    function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <useLocation> 
      {({ useLocation }) => { 
        if (useLocation.pathname !== "/") { return <Navbar/>; } }
      } 
    </useLocation>
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome}/>
      <Route path="/Home" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/About" component={About}/>
      <Route path='/Whitepaper' component={WhitePaper}/>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is `useLocation` in this snippet? This seems totally incorrect. Are you trying to use the `useLocation` React hook from `react-router-dom`?

Comment: what is useLocation? It looks like a hook but you used it as Component? React component must start with a capital letter.

Comment: I tried to use location but kept getting errors. I am new to react therefore not really sure how to correct this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have better luck rendering the `Navbar` component into a route and checking the passed `location` from [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

### `react-router-dom@5`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route
        render={({ location }) => location.pathname !== "/" ? <Navbar /> : null}
      />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
      <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/About" component={About} />
      <Route path='/Whitepaper' component={WhitePaper} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

### `react-router-dom@6`

If using `react-router-dom@6` then you can create a layout route the renders the `NavBar` component and an `Outlet` for nested routes.

Example:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const NavLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Welcome />} />
        <Route element={<NavLayout />}>
          <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
          <Route path='/Whitepaper' element={<WhitePaper />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```